# How to extract by referring to its date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have df like following one

```
customer  movement      date
A         buy      2019/5/4 
A        inquiry   2020/7/1
A        cancel    2020/8/1
B         buy      2019/6/1
B        cancel    2020/8/1
```

I'd like to trace each customer's `movement` before `cancel`

first, grouping by `customer`

```
A         buy      2019/5/4 
A        inquiry   2020/7/1
A        cancel    2020/8/1
```

Then I'd like to get `cancel date`

```
A        cancel    2020/8/1
```

And then,I'd like to get `previous movement` before cancel `in 1 year`.

```
customer movement date
A        inquiry  2020/7/1
A        cancel   2020/8/1
```

After that , I'd like to repeat in each `customers`

So my desired result is like below

```
customer movement date
A        inquiry  2020/7/1
A        cancel   2020/8/1
B        cancel   2020/8/1
```

Are there any way to achieve this?
This is totally complicated that I couldn't handle such procedure..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert column to datetimes and create Series with filtered only `cancel` rows by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

s = df[df['movement'].eq('cancel')].set_index('customer')['date']
```

Then mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) years subtracted by 1 year and filter for less values of `date` column by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['customer'].map(s.sub(pd.DateOffset(years=1))).lt(df['date'])]
print (df)
  customer movement       date
1        A  inquiry 2020-07-01
2        A   cancel 2020-08-01
4        B   cancel 2020-08-01
```